# Why are the text sticking below the image inside a CSS unordered list menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this JSFiddle which works correctly (the CSS is just a barebone): http://jsfiddle.net/b6w9yfq3/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="navMenu" class="navMenu hidOverflow">
                            <ul class="brClear">
                                <li><a href="#portfolio" class="jumplink"><span class="navIcon"><img src="theImages/portfolio.png" /></span>Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about" class="jumplink"><span class="navIcon"><img src="theImages/about.png" /></span>About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact" class="jumplink"><span class="navIcon"><img src="theImages/contact.png" /></span>Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#forum" class="jumplink"><span class="navIcon"><img src="theImages/forum.png" /></span>Forum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Also, How do I make it so the extra space at the end of the menu isn't there. I originally had 5 entries but when I shortened it to 4, the 5th space is still showing up.

How do I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very straightforward. The image used for `Contact` has 21px of height, the rest of the icons all have 26 px of height.

Simply add 5px of padding to the bottom of that particular icon, or stretch it, up to you.

For part 2, change the width of the li elements from 20% to 25%.

```
.navMenu ul li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: thanks but why is the barebone jsfiddle shows up fine?

Comment: Because those are all broken images that have the same height/width .

Comment: I got you... I will make a new image same size... How abt the 5th empty space?

Comment: You are right... Thanks. Any idea about the empty LI?